# Built up Pressure Treated 6x6 post from 2x4s?

Tags: wood, post

I'd like to use a PT 6x6x12 post to attach a shade sail to but PT 6x6x12 has been impossible to find locally for a long time.

I'm thinking about building it up out of 4 PT 2x4x12s. Any reason NOT to do that?

I'm thinking it'll be more twist-resistant too.  Any advise on glue/screw/laminating them?

Not relevant to the question, but FYI will burried 2-3 feet into a concrete foundation. I want the top at least 8' above ground.  I'm also planning on using at least one guy wire from the top to the ground. I have also considered putting 2"x2" square galvanized steel sign posts in the middle but that seems overkill.  This is Southern Calfiornia, so high winds (Santa Anas), but not hurricanes or tornados.

[image]

Comment: There may be some good information here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136336/build-6x6-single-post-from-2x4s-for-swingset

Comment: If you're already thinking about adding a metal post, why not just the metal post?  You'd be able to get away with much smaller than 6x6.  I've had shade sails mounted on 2x2 angle survive 70+ mph winds.

Comment: My understanding of a shade sail is they are not that heavy, but do need a good anchoring to the ground, so that wind does not pick them up.  A 4x4 or two 2x4s screwed/nailed together should hold it up.  Might want a couple of rods in holes near the bottom, for the cement to hold onto.

Comment: It should be plenty strong with glue/screws.

Comment: Consider Iron fence post instead. Up. to 12 feet long, about 2 inches diameter, made from rust free metal. Strong, wont bend. It is easier. to drill 2 inch hole in concrete

Comment: The problem with a light surface/roof you want a rough/pieces sticking out of the post near the bottom to anchor into the cement/stone/dirt.  The wind will pull out any smooth wall post.

Comment: Can't be conclusive without more info about the sail and the geometry of it but usually the guy wire would be doing most of the work, you need to focus on the guy wire's anchor, and this 6x6 structure would be overkill.  What forced are you thinking will be fought with the built up, hollow, 6x6 structure?

Comment: Go to a woodyard, they will cut one to size.

Comment: FYI: Your build up with yield an actual 5" x 5" post. A 6x6" post will be 5.5" x 5.5" actual size. Just in case that impacts any of your designs or plans.

Comment: TY all. I did read that DIY Q, but it's about a non-PT beam, and the answers not particularly useful so I felt a new Q was worthwhile.

4x4 w/ 8' sticking out of the ground and the end unrestrained just seems like a really long moment arm to me. A guywire I think will help tremendously in one direction, but only that direction.   I also would prefer the look of larger lumber.  

I did consider a 2-4" tubular steel post, but again can't find it locally and the out-of-stock pricing looks expensive.